# Creating Wizard Using Jquery

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1"></div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2"></div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3"></div>
</div>


<ul class="pager wizard">
  <li class="previous"><a href="javascript:;">Previous</a>
  </li>
  <li class="next"><a href="javascript:;">Next</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('ul.pager li').click(function(e) 
            {
               var bname = $(this).attr("class");
               if(bname=='next'){
                    var actdiv  = $(".tab-content").find('.tab-pane,.active').attr("id");
                    $('#'+actdiv).removeClass("active");
                    var divs = actdiv.slice(-1);
                    console.log(parseInt(divs) + 1);
                    var nextdiv = '#tab'+(parseInt(divs) + 1);
                    //console.log(nextdiv);
                    $(".tab-content").find(nextdiv).addClass("active");    
               } else {
                    var actdiv  = $(".tab-content").find('.tab-pane,.active').attr("id").slice(-1);
                    $(".tab-content").find('.tab-pane').removeClass("active");
                    var prediv = 'tab'+(parseInt(actdiv) - 1);
                    console.log(prediv);
                    $(".tab-content").find(prediv).addClass("active");
               }

            });
        });
```

When I click on next for first time it remove active class from tab-1 and add active class to tab-2 but when I click on next again, it gets stuck.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : you can put two different click handlers for previous and next button. You have little complex logic to calculate next and previous tab and there you have mistaken the calculation of next / previous tab id using `.slice()`. Instead you can use below logic, see below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.pager li.previous').click(function(e) 
    {
       var $activeTab = $('div.tab-content div.tab-pane.active');
      //check if previous tab present
       if($activeTab.prev('div.tab-pane').length > 0)
       {
         $activeTab.removeClass('active');
         $activeTab.prev('div.tab-pane').addClass('active');
       }
    });

    $('ul.pager li.next').click(function(e) 
    {
       var $activeTab = $('div.tab-content div.tab-pane.active');
      //check if next tab present
       if($activeTab.next('div.tab-pane').length > 0)
       {
         $activeTab.removeClass('active');
         $activeTab.next('div.tab-pane').addClass('active');
       }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank You sir...+1 from my side.

Answer (score 0):

I always believe in minimized code. I see you are doing lot of calculations to get the target tab which has to be activated next. jQuery has pretty decent selecter methods which helps you to do this. Try the code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".pager").on("click", ">li", function(){
        var $activeTab = $(".active", ".tab-content"),
            $target = $(this).hasClass("next") ? $activeTab.next() : $activeTab.prev();
        
        //
     if($target.length){
            $activeTab.removeClass("active");
         $target.addClass("active");
        }
    }); 
});
```

```css
.tab-pane{
    display:none;
    background: #EEE;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align:center;
}

.tab-pane.active{
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-content">
 <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">    tab 1                     
 </div>
 <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">  tab 2
 </div>
 <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">  tab 3
 </div>
</div>
<ul class="pager wizard">
 <li class="previous"><a href="javascript:;">Previous</a></li>
 <li class="next"><a href="javascript:;">Next</a></li>
</ul>
```

You can make this circular with little bit of code change. Try this here: http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/zLg842ye/1/

Comment: Nice Answer....But problem is this is circular 1,2,3 then 1.I need 1,2,3, Stop and reverse.

Comment: For circular, I have given the reference code. See this...http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/zLg842ye/

Comment: Fiddle is doing 1,2,3 and then 1.But i need 1,2,3 and Stop and vise versa

Comment: The above code doesn't repeats it. This does 1, 2, 3 and then stops.

Comment: I dont have enough repu. to upvote. Your answer is also correct. +1. Thanks